# Redefine global math mode to give source on selection/copy

Tags: math-mode, accsupp

Currently, I have the following setup wich works to return the LaTeX source code on selection/copy in the PDF output.

I am wondering if it is possible to redefine mathmode or `$` to wrap its contents in the \copyable command.

The result I am hoping for is that all text typeset in mathmode can easily be copied from the generated PDF without the person typesetting the document to have to do more work.

```
\documentclass{report}

\RequirePackage{accsupp}

\newcommand*{\copyable}[1]{%
  \BeginAccSupp{%
    ActualText=\detokenize{#1},%
    method=escape,
  }%
  #1%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}

\begin{document}

\copyable{\( a-b \ne c+1\)}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT after comment** -
I came up with this for now as a workaround for inline math and display math.

*`\cf` for "copyable formula".*

```
\protected\def\cf{\@ifnextchar[\@copymathDisplay\@copymathInline}
\def\@copymathDisplay[#1\]{\copyable{\[#1\]}}
\def\@copymathInline(#1\){\copyable{\(#1\)}}
```

However, I would like to have it take effect everywhere in the document where math mode is used. 
Such that also takes effect when used in environments like for example `eqnarray`.

Comment: If you are using `\( .. \)` you can probably use `etoolbox` package and do `\preto\({\BeginAccSupp{..}}` and `\appto\){\endAccSupp{}}`.

Comment: I am looking to redefine the internal mathmode in such a way that this takes effect on all environments which use it too. Updated my answer to reflect this.